PHP Agent Installer Task Execution
Experiencing an issue during the installation of the New Relic PHP Agent. The installation fails during the task send_transaction with the following error:
{"err":"task: Failed to run task \"default\": task: Failed to run task \"send_transaction\": exit status 1","level":"debug","msg":"Task execution returned error","time":"2024-12-02T11:54:03Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"Invalid JSON string found in output file, skipping: ","time":"2024-12-02T11:54:03Z"}
{"error":"execution failed for php-agent-installer: exit status 1: \u001b[0;36m===\u003e \u001b[0;97mSend queryable transactions\u001b[38;5;240m","guid":"","level":"debug","msg":"recipe event","recipe_name":"php-agent-installer","status":"FAILED","statusCount":10,"tasks":["default","send_transaction"],"time":"2024-12-02T11:54:03Z","validationDurationMs":0}
{"level":"debug","msg":"install error encountered: exit status 1: \u001b[0;36m===\u003e \u001b[0;97mSend queryable transactions\u001b[38;5;240m","time":"2024-12-02T11:54:03Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"Failed while executing and validating with progress for recipe name php-agent-installer, detail:exit status 1: \u001b[0;36m===\u003e \u001b[0;97mSend queryable transactions\u001b[38;5;240m","time":"2024-12-02T11:54:03Z"}

The installation process logs show several debug messages, including:

Invalid JSON string found in the output file

Error while executing the recipe php-agent-installer

The installation of other recommended integrations (e.g., Memcached
and Varnish Cache) was successful, but the PHP Agent installer fails.


Installation script:
curl -Ls https://download.newrelic.com/install/newrelic-cli/scripts/install.sh | bash && sudo NEW_RELIC_API_KEY=NRAK-XXXX NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID=XXXXX /usr/local/bin/newrelic install -n php-agent-installer

Newrelic version: 0.97.1 | AGENT VERSION: 11.3.0.16
PHP version: 8.1.30 same issue with PHP 7.4.33
New Relic Infrastructure Agent version: 1.58.0, GoVersion: go1.22.9, GitCommit: 1a19023b867cc2aac94959aa1bb82e3b53cb4d48, BuildDate: 2024-11-07T09:10:28Z
Environment: Debian 11
 nc -vz collector.newrelic.com 443
Connection to collector.newrelic.com (162.247.243.32) 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!

PHP Agent Logs:
2024-12-02 15:59:58.824 +0000 (3320354 3320354) info: attempt daemon connection via '@newrelic'
2024-12-02 15:59:58.824 +0000 (3320354 3320354) info: New Relic 11.3.0.16 ("corundum" - "f30642fd4f51") [daemon='@newrelic'  php='7.4.33' zts=no sapi='fpm-fcgi'  pid=3320354 ppid=1 uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0 backtrace=yes startup=agent os='Linux' rel='5.10.0-26-amd64' mach='x86_64' ver='#1 SMP Debian 5.10.197-1 (2023-09-29)' node='1210295.cloudwaysapps.com']

New-Relic Logs:
{
  "agentName": "Infrastructure",
  "agentVersion": "1.58.0",
  "apmApplicationIds": "|563270270|",
  "apmApplicationNames": "|test|",
  "coreCount": "2",
  "entity.guid.INFRA": "NDYxNTE3NXxJTkZSQXxOQXw0OTUxODM0NzU5NzcyOTg5MTQy",
  "entity.guids": "NDYxNTE3NXxJTkZSQXxOQXw0OTUxODM0NzU5NzcyOTg5MTQy",
  "fb.input": "tail",
  "filePath": "/root/.newrelic/newrelic-cli.log",
  "fullHostname": "1210295.cloudwaysapps.com",
  "hostname": "1210295.cloudwaysapps.com",
  "hostStatus": "running",
  "instanceType": "DigitalOcean Droplet",
  "kernelVersion": "5.10.0-26-amd64",
  "level": "debug",
  "linuxDistribution": "Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)",
  "logtype": "newrelic-cli",
  "message": "Failed while executing and validating with progress for recipe name php-agent-installer, detail:exit status 1: \u001b[0;36m===> \u001b[0;97mSend queryable transactions\u001b[38;5;240m",
  "newrelic-cli": "true",
  "newrelic.source": "api.logs",
  "nr_deployed_by": "newrelic-cli",
  "operatingSystem": "linux",
  "plugin.source": "BARE-METAL",
  "plugin.type": "nri-agent",
  "plugin.version": "1.19.1",
  "processorCount": "2",
  "systemMemoryBytes": "4109836288",
  "time": "2024-12-02T16:30:43Z",
  "timestamp": 1733157043655
}

